# Family visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration

I have a visitor's visa for UK, which will expire on 14 April 2019. If I enter the UK on 10 April 2019, do I have to exit on 14 April 2019 ? 
My plan is to stay there for about 30 days, Or the immigration officer will allow a certain period to stay ?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike USA visitor visas where the expiry date signifies the latest date by which you can travel to the USA to request permission to enter and be given an authorised period of stay, the expiry date on a UK visa is the date by which you must leave. If you arrive on 10 April you will have to leave on or before 14 April. If you want to stay for 30 days you will need to change your travel date or obtain a new visa before travelling to the UK. Extensions to a UK Standard Visitor visa are not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Immigration Officers implement immigration Laws. And as per Law you have to leave the country before expiry of your Visa. Immigration Officer will not be satisfied with these dates. Actually before giving entry they usually ask about return tickets and your departure programme and logically no one is coming for 04 days and if you stay after expiry it will also ruin your travel history. Better you put a fresh application for Visa so that your travel histry and also you yourself dont feel panic.

Comment: Many visitors come to the UK for short stays. A visit of 4 days isn’t necessarily illogical.